# How do I read multiple floats from the same line with a scanner?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm a new programmer, and for an assignment I have to write a program that asks the user to enter three numbers, and returns the smallest to them. I don't know how to make each entry it's own float. So far, I have:

```
static float smallest(float a, float b, float c);

System.out.println("Enter three numbers");
```

I don't know how to clarify that the next line holds the floats for a, b, and c. We also just learned what "static float smallest" means, and I'm still very confused, so I'm sorry if the answer is obvious.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask should help.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class MyClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter three numbers");

    float a = myObj.nextFloat();
    float b = myObj.nextFloat();
    float c = myObj.nextFloat();

    System.out.println("Smallest numb: " + smallest(a, b, c));

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change println to print

```
System.out.print("Enter three numbers: ");
```

and

use **useDelimiter(pattern)** in java.util.Scanner

```
Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\s* \\s*");
```

Answer (score -1):

From the *javadoc* for class [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.

This means you can enter three `float` numbers separated by a space on one line and read all three with a `Scanner`.

Apparently you want your program to accept these three numbers from the user. Hence you can create a `Scanner` that wraps the standard input, i.e. `System.in`. Example code follows:

```java
float a;
float b;
float c;
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter three numbers: ");
if (stdin.hasNextFloat()) {
    a = stdin.nextFloat();
}
if (stdin.hasNextFloat()) {
    b = stdin.nextFloat();
}
if (stdin.hasNextFloat()) {
    c = stdin.nextFloat();
}
```

Note that the above code only accepts three `float` numbers but does not determine which of them is the smallest - since you only asked how to accept three `float` numbers.

Here is an example of running the above code:

```
Enter three numbers: 1.1 2.2 3.55
```